# Which SELinux setting prevents module upload via Admin interface?

Tags: 7, files

Just wondering if anyone knows which SELinux boolean(s) is/are blocking the installation of new modules via the admin (FTP) upload interface. I have VSFTPD installed, and can upload via FTP client. I just wanted to know for future reference. If I use "setenforce 0", it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have pegged the variable in question!

```
setsebool httpd_can_network_connect on
```

This allows the web server to connect to the FTP server. So, if you have set up an FTP server and account, but still can't upload modules to Drupal via the front end, try the above command!